# Console.log not working javascript/jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, console

I am trying to get started with javascript, but I can't see to get console.log to work.

In the `head`, I load jquery as follows:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Then, right before the end of `body`, I place the document.ready function as follows:

```
$( document ).ready(function() {
console.log( "ready!" );
});
```

No other javascript/jquery is present in the file.  I expected the phrase "ready!" to be logged to the console, but instead, nothing happened.  How can I fix this?

Comment: If your page is loading over https then it won't work.  Doubtful this is your issue, but you should go ahead and use `https` in your `src` when you load jquery.

Comment: Thank you for the pointer, Josh!

Comment: *"I am trying to get started with javascript..."* You have JavaScript questions going back a month and a half. How did you manage to get your previous scripts to run? If you didn't have `<script>` tags as suggested below, then didn't you notice the text of the script [show up on the page](https://jsfiddle.net/k6aymf5u/)?

Comment: This whole question gave me a really goo laugh.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you need to wrap your code in a `<script>` tag

Comment: Yep, that is it.  Thank you very much, and I'll accept your answer as soon as I can.

Comment: Easiest 40 points anyone has ever acquired in this site..

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown 99.9% of the users here would assume OP just didn't include the Script tag in the post because who would not know to put in a script tag. wolfman6377 is that .1% who dared and won.

Comment: @mattfetz I was actually just kidding about it. Also, I have upvoted him.